# One root of the equation $x^2 + px + q = 0$ is $n$ times the other

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> One root of the equation $x^2 + px + q = 0$ is $n$ times the other, where $n ≠ 0$.
> Show that $qn^2 + (2q – p^2)n + q = 0$.

These are the answers. This is what I don't get... Someone explain to me how they got to this conclusion
[image: answers]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Which of the four lines of the given answer bothers  you?

Comment: I don't get the transition from 2nd line to the third line

Comment: Note that alternatively you can assume the roots $\alpha, n\alpha$ and then plug the Vieta's formulas $q=\alpha^2n$ and $p=-n\alpha-\alpha$ into the $qn^2+(2q-p^2)n+q$ to see it simplifies to $0$.

Answer (score 4):

The first line of the solution is a direct application of the quadratic formula.

> Quadratic Formula
>
> If $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ where $a \neq 0$, then
> $x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.

The second line is because of the fact that one root is $n$ times the other.

From second to third line, expansion will do the job.
$$-p + \sqrt{p^2 - 4q} = -np -n\sqrt{p^2 - 4q}$$
$$\sqrt{p^2 - 4q} + n\sqrt{p^2 - 4q}=-np+p$$
$$\sqrt{p^2 - 4q}= \frac{-np+p}{1+n}$$
We then square both sides of the equation.
$$p^2 - 4q = \frac{(-np+p)^2}{(1+n)^2}$$
Now, multiply the denominator to the LHS, expand both brackets and group the terms in descending order of $n$. We shall get the answer.

Comment: Wow, that helped well! Thank you for expanding everything!

Answer (score -1):

Here, They use Sridhar Acharya's Rule to find out root of Quadratic equation.

After finding roots of given equation,use the condition given in your question & then simplify it.
You will get required answer.